# How to get push notification message when the user click the App directly?

Tags: ios, push-notification

When the push notification arrived, user click the app directly , the push notification remain in notification center. how can i get the message from notification center ? i want to get it and save it locally so users can view them later.

I can save the push notification if i click the alert from the notification center when the push notification arrived. or i can save the push notification when the app is running.

in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

    //save the alert
    [FunctionNSObject savePushNotification:userInfo];
}
```

in MyTableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //load push notification from file
    sortedMessages = [FunctionNSObject loadPushNotification];
}
```

Comment: you can save push notification when application is close and get notification after click on application icon.other wise you can save all notification.

Comment: would you pls show me the code ? and which event i am missing in AppDelegate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is flawed--push notifications are meant to be transient, they can be tied to an event (such as an email being received) but they are not the event itself.  In the email example, all the push is supposed to do is to tell the email app that there is a new email and maybe contain some content that will give a hint to the email content, but the actual content of the email is not the job of the notification to deliver--that needs to be fetched separately.  APNS is a system for sending events to remote clients, it is not the content system itself.

The way systems like Facebook or whatsapp deal with this is that they have their own message system and they use APNS to inform the applications that there is a new message in the inbox, then the app will fetch the content for the user by pulling it from the server.

If you want to build a system like this then you can still use APNS but APNS should inform your client that there is new content available to fetch and you will need a server that manages the cloud inbox.

Comment: i am using parse.com for the push notification. do you know i can download the previous push notification through the Parse API or Parse Webservice ?

Comment: You are still missing the point of what I am saying.  You don't want to download a previous notification, you want to download the CONTENT that caused the notification to be pushed in the first place.  How you structure that depends on your API but again go back to the email example: the push just tells the client it has a new message, what you want to download is the message itself.

Comment: there is no content update , i use the push notification push some news to the clients. so push notification message is the only thing i want to show. if so i have to create duplicate message, one for push notification and one for webservice download ? that sounds stupid = =

Comment: The push should not be the source of the content, it can include content for the purpose of informing the user what the notification is about but if there is actual news you should be getting the information from a server because you can't guarantee that the push will reach your app.  Just because it is possible to deliver the full data payload to the client doesn't mean it is a good design.  You asked how whatsapp does this and I told you, every messaging system that works the way you are discussing stores the master content on the server and does not rely on the push.

Comment: I just finish the setup, when sending out the push notification, i will save the message to my DB and when the app launch it get the message from our web service via REST. so we cannot the web interface or iphone app push4parse provided by parse.com to send push notification. we using the REST API provided by parse.com to integrated into our system

Answer (score 2):

you can add below code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if ([[launchOptions allKeys] containsObject:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {

        id userInfo=[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    }
```

this method call when application is close and click on notification and you only get this notification info

Comment: have you receive notification?

Comment: yes, i can receive notification. i can save the notification when the app is forefront or click the notification go to the app. but when the notification arrived, i click the app directly, the notification is null in the app. the problem is when people click the app directly, they will miss the push notification

Comment: yes, you r right, you can't get notification info if you click on icon after rereive notification.only receive click on notification.

Comment: how to handle this senario, like whatsapp, we can click the app directly to get into the app the see the notification

Comment: using webservices only, no other solution